# Which is preferable in a compound model: Monte Carlo simulation or normal approximation?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, simulation

I have a random variable $Y$ defined as a sum of identical Exponential random variables.  The number of those Exponential random variables is Poisson.  So $Y$ has finite mean and variance.

I have simulated $2000$ values of $Y$.

I am now estimating $P[Y<3000]$.

Which would give me a better estimation: a normal approximation or just using the simulated values?

In other words, I'm thinking of

Normal Approximation: $$P[Z<\frac{(3000 - \text{ sample mean })}{(\text{ sample standard deviation })}]$$

Simulated values: $\dfrac{\text{sum}(Y < 3000)}{2000}$ (summing over the 2000 simulated values)

I thought that increasing the number of simulated values would be best, so that $Y$ gets closer to a normal distribution by the Central Limit Theorem. But I cannot concretely say why that would be better.

Edit: Given that we have a Poisson and Exponential we can compute the real value of the mean and standard deviation.  Perhaps it is these values that should go into the normal approximation instead of the sample mean and variance.

Comment: That depends: what's the parameter for the Poisson that is the number of variables you are summing?

Comment: I think the question you mean to ask is how many samples would you need to simulate for the Monte Carlo estimation of the probability to be more accurate than the normal approximation. But I wouldn't rule out other alternatives -- note that the p.d.f of a sum of random variables is the convolution of their separate p.d.f.s

Comment: The Poisson parameter (mean) is 5.  And theta = 500 for the Exponential.

Comment: @Ian Did I do the normal approximation correctly or should it be what I mentioned in the Edit?

Comment: With the Poisson parameter being 5, I would think that the normal approximation would not be very good.

Comment: @Ian Can you elaborate or point to a resource?  I can't understand why.  In my calculations I get the difference between simulated and normal approximation to be 0.009217.

Comment: For instance the typical value of that Poisson is 5 so you are typically adding up about 5 exponential variables, I would be surprised if the sum of 5 exponential variables behaved much like the normal with the same mean and variance. In particular the right tail should be quite a bit heavier than it is in the normal.

Comment: @Ian Right, I saw that in the plot of the kernel density (I'm using R).  But then how does the CLT fit in?